# Displaying Unicode characters in PDF produced by Apache FOP

Tags: unicode, fonts, apache-fop

I have an XML file containing a list of names, some of which use characters/glyphs which are not represented in the default PDF font (Helvetica/Arial):

```
<name>Paul</name>
<name>你好</name>
```

I'm processing this file using XSLT and Apache FOP to produce a PDF file which lists the names. Currently I'm getting the following warning on the console and the Chinese characters are replaced by ## in the PDF:

```
Jan 30, 2016 11:30:56 AM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent WARNING: Glyph "你" (0x4f60) not available in font "Helvetica".
Jan 30, 2016 11:30:56 AM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent WARNING: Glyph "好" (0x597d) not available in font "Helvetica".
```

I've looked at the documentation and it seems to suggest that the options available are:

1. Use an OpenType font - except this isn't supported by FOP.
2. Switch to a different font just for the non-ASCII parts of text.

I don't want to use different fonts for each language, because there will be PDFs that have a mixture of Chinese and English, and as far as I know there's no way to work out which is which in XSLT/XSL-FO.

Is it possible to embed a single font to cover all situations? At the moment I just need English and Chinese, but I'll probably need to extend that in future.

I'm using Apache FOP 2.1 and Java 1.7.0_91 on Ubuntu. I've seen some earlier questions on a similar topic but most seem to be using a much older version of Apache FOP (e.g. 0.95 or 1.1) and I don't know if anything has been changed/improved in the meantime.

**Edit:** My question is different (I think) to the suggested duplicate. I've switched to using the [Ubuntu Font Family](http://font.ubuntu.com/) using the following code in my FOP config:

```
<font kerning="yes" embed-url="../fonts/ubuntu/Ubuntu-R.ttf" embedding-mode="full">
   <font-triplet name="Ubuntu" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
</font>

<font kerning="yes" embed-url="../fonts/ubuntu/Ubuntu-B.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
   <font-triplet name="Ubuntu" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
</font>
```

However, I'm still getting the 'glyph not available' warning:

```
Jan 31, 2016 10:22:59 AM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
WARNING: Glyph "你" (0x4f60) not available in font "Ubuntu".
Jan 31, 2016 10:22:59 AM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
WARNING: Glyph "好" (0x597d) not available in font "Ubuntu".
```

I know Ubuntu Regular has these two glyphs because it's my standard system font.

**Edit 2:** If I use [GNU Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html), the glyphs display correctly. However, it seems to be a font aimed more at console use than in documents.

Comment: How is 2 any different from 1? https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.0/fonts.html suggests OpenType ttf/otf fonts are supported just fine, so you should probably try that first. You might not be able to use all the OpenType features, but if you rely on those to begin with, FOP wouldn't have been your technology of choice anyway.

Comment: In similar questions, users reported successfully using Arial Unicode for documents containing different languages (I'm sure other there are other fonts too).

Comment: Arial Unicode is an issue for me due to licensing restrictions (I need to be able to ship whatever embedded fonts I use with the software). I've tried using Ubuntu Regular which definitely displays 你好 correctly when I use it  on my system but I still get a warning about the glyph not being available.

Comment: Alas, you are being bamboozled by the software you are using to display that string "Ubuntu Regular which definitely displays 你好 correctly". The [very latest version](http://font.ubuntu.com) does **not** contain any Chinese characters at all.

Comment: According to http://font.ubuntu.com/about/, The Ubuntu Font Family has 1200 glyphs. That does not sound too impressive. How can it cover Chinese with so few glyphs? Arial Unicode has more than 50 000 glyphs. Am I missing something?

Comment: @mzjn: it might still be possible that for some random reason its designer included an (infinitelisimally small) fraction of Chinese glyphs in the font, including the 2 characters pwaring tested with. But I took the obvious route and downloaded the latest version and checked with InDesign. It's all Greek to me - plus Cyrillic and lots of Extended Latin. But no Chinese.

Comment: Okay, if Ubuntu Regular doesn't include Chinese (though I'm still not entirely sure why it works in LibreOffice but not Apache FOP), what are my options?

Comment: Concerning LibreOffice, I think it may be automatically using some default font supporting CJK glyphs whenever the user-selected one does not (apparently OpenOffice and MS Word do the same). Proof: see what happens when you select for your Chinese text a font that surely does **not** have Chinese glyphs (a "fancy" font is probably a good candidate).

Comment: There's multiple free CJK fonts.  E.g., Source Hans Sans (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Han_Sans) or the other entries marked '[F]' in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_fonts

Comment: The problem isn't finding a Chinese font, it's finding a font where I can mix Chinese and English (and possibly other languages), since I have no way of detecting which language a name will be in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question is either use [GNU Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html), which:

1. Supports Chinese and English.
2. Is available under a free licence.
3. 'Just works' if you add it to the FOP config file.

Or alternatively produce separate templates for English and Chinese PDFs and use different fonts for each.

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot find a suitable font supporting *both* Chinese and English (or you found one, but you don't like very much its latin glyphs), remember that `font-family` can contain **a comma-separated list of names**, to be used in that order.

So, you can list your desired font for English text first, and then the one for the Chinese text:

```
<!-- this has # instead of the missing Chinese glyphs -->
<fo:block font-family="Helvetica" space-after="1em" background-color="#AAFFFF">
    Paul 你好</fo:block>

<!-- this has all the glyphs, but I don't like its latin glyphs -->
<fo:block font-family="SimSun" space-after="1em" background-color="#FFAAFF">
    Paul 你好</fo:block>

<!-- the best of both worlds! -->
<fo:block font-family="Helvetica, SimSun" space-after="1em" background-color="#FFFFAA">
    Paul 你好</fo:block>
```

The output looks like this:

[image: screenshot of PDF output]

Comment: I wasn't aware you could use fonts like that, I thought it was a case of using the first font in the list and the second would only be used if the first wasn't installed/embedded.