# SVG to PDF conversion doesn't render Cyrillic characters correctly

Tags: apache-fop, batik

I'm trying to convert a SVG which has **Cyrillic characters to PDF document but those are showing as #.** I have gone through few threads reporting similar issue but could not found solution.

PDF is getting generated with below warnings:

```
About to transcoder source of type: org.apache.batik.apps.rasterizer.SVGConverterFileSource

Aug 10, 2021 5:36:56 PM org.apache.fop.fonts.Typeface warnMissingGlyph

WARNING: Glyph 12362 (0x304a, ohiragana) not available in font Helvetica

Aug 10, 2021 5:36:56 PM org.apache.fop.fonts.Typeface warnMissingGlyph

WARNING: Glyph 12397 (0x306d, nehiragana) not available in font Helvetica
```

In input svg, we don't have any font-family specified.

As mentioned on few threads I need to define font that has glyph for required characters. The question is how to do that? Can you please provide some link which will guide through steps for defining fonts?

Comment: It looks like certain Hiragana (Japanese) glyphs are missing, not Cyrillic ones.

Comment: "I have gone through few threads"? What threads? There are several similar old questions related to fonts, for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/60281589/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/35101439/407651.